# How to split dataframe into different plots in R?

Tags: r

I have a csv of the form

```
latency1, latency2, test-type
1.3233831,1.0406423,A
1.6799337,1.1520619,A
1.6301824,1.1536479,B
2.3465363,1,2346457,C
1.2452355,1.9987547,C
...
```

I want to graph three different plots: one with latency1 vs latency2 for type A, one with latency1 vs latency2 for type B, and one with latency1 vs latency2 for type C. I know how to graph different data sets on the same graph, but not how to split one dataframe into multiple plots like this. I'm an R newbie, sorry. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting functions in the **lattice** package have a formula interface whose `|` operator allows you to indicate a conditioning variable used to split the data into a "lattice" or "trellis" of separate plots.

Try this, for example:

```
## Read in your data
df <- read.table(text="latency1, latency2, testType
1.3233831,1.0406423,A
1.6799337,1.1520619,A
1.6301824,1.1536479,B
2.3465363,1.2346457,C
1.2452355,1.9987547,C", header=T, sep=",")


library(lattice)
xyplot(latency2 ~ latency1 | testType, data = df, type = "b")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Faceted plot

[image: faceted plot]

### Code

In case you want to do this with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = read.table(text='latency1,latency2,testtype
1.3233831,1.0406423,A
1.6799337,1.1520619,A
1.6301824,1.1536479,B
2.3465363,1.2346457,C
1.2452355,1.9987547,C', 
                header=TRUE, sep=',')

p = ggplot(data = df, 
           aes(x = latency1, y = latency2, colour = testtype)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid( . ~ testtype )

p
```